# Problem with white square notification icons after FCM V1 upgrade

Tags: push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I upgraded to v1 since legacy will shut down, but during tests I realise that my icons are white square im V1 but showing correctly in legacy.

I didn't find any solution on the internet, since my icon is correctly shown on legacy but not on V1.

Do you have any idea of what is going on?

See image below
[image]